# Selenium documentation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can see from other online sources that the getAttribute method is part of the WebElement interface,I could find this information on other sites but nothing regarding this interface and method in the Selenium documentation. Is this interface no longer supported? What is the best practice if this interface is no longer supported?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `WebElement` interface and specifically the method `getAttribute` is rather extensive:

See [the javadoc](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))

Comment: Is there any documentation in the new Selenium website? If so, why not?